# Как не блокировать главный поток после pthread_join?

Tags: c, многопоточность, асинхронность, pthread

Есть код:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void threading_foo( void * threaded_data ) {
  sleep(5);
  printf("\nthreaded");
  pthread_exit(0);
}

void create_threads() {
  void * thread_data = NULL;
  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, threading_foo, thread_data);
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  printf("MAIN");
}

int main() {
  void * thread_data = NULL;
  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, create_threads, thread_data);
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Я новенький в `pthread`. И ожидал поведения как в `JS` при вызове `setTimeout`, к примеру. То есть, сначала выводится надпись "MAIN", а затем после 5 секунд -- надпись "threaded".

Но, как я понял, поток блокируется до тех пор, пока не завершится дочерний. Вопрос: как реализовать поведение `setTimeout` с помощью pthread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pthread_join ждет завершения потока. Поэтому, вначале завершится поток threading_foo, а потом только create_threads. И выведет "\nthreadedMain".

pthread_join перпендикуляре js'ому setTimeout

> Как не блокировать главный поток после pthread_join?

блокирует именно вызов pthread_join. Не хотите блокировать - не вызывайте сразу, а позже. В си нужно следить за ресурсами аккуратно, здесь нет уборщика мусора.

Comment: С мусором спасибо, это я потом разберусь. Что значит не вызывать сразу? Приведите простой пример пожалуйста, который бы эмулировал setTimeout? Для меня важно, чтоб тред начал работу без блокирования потока. Тобишь вывод: "MAIN\nthreaded"

Comment: переставьте местами строки `pthread_join(thread, NULL);` и
  `printf("MAIN");`

Comment: Но ведь это лишь создаст видимость параллельной работы, не более того?

Comment: c это не js. Здесь есть полноценные потоки. и если запустить десять потоков, то они будут работать в паралель (если есть достаточно ресурсов у процессора) и в коде нет блокировок.